# Ruby Extract array from multi-dimensional array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have a multidimensional array like:

```
arr1 = [["text1", 1], ["text2", 2], ["&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;text3", 3], ["&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;text4", 4], ["text5", 5], ["text6", 6], ["text7", 7]]
```

and another

```
arr2 = [2,3,6]
```

I want to extract entire array if it contains elements of arr2. So, result should be:

```
arr = [["text2", 2], ["&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;text3", 3], ["text6", 6]].
```

I've tried many ways but unable to get the result. Attempts such as:

```
arr1.each { |elem| arr2.each { |x| elem.delete_if{ |u| elem.include?(x) } } }
```

and

```
arr2.map { |x| arr1.map{|key, val| val.include?(x) }}
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arr1.inject([]) { |result, array| (array & arr2).any? ? result << array : result }
#=> [["text2", 2], ["&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;text3", 3], ["text6", 6]]
```

Slightly shorter and more correct from the goal perspective:

```
arr1.select { |array| (array & arr2).any? }
```

Comment: Why not `arr1.select { |a| (a & arr2).any? }` or `arr1.find_all { |a| (a & arr2).any? }` since you are selecting/finding things rather than a more general injection/reduction?

Comment: @muistooshort selecting is definitely better than building a new array (which I did), I'll edit the answer (i did not do that before because solutions with `select` were already given)..

Answer (score 3):

Try this one

```
arr1.select { |a| a.any? { |item| arr2.include? item } }
 => [["text2", 2], ["&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;text3", 3], ["text6", 6]]
```

Comment: I prefer this or the first comment of the accepted answer as it is more clearly related to what the code is trying to do, i.e. finding something.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr1.select { |(_, d)| arr2.include? d }
```

Comment: Not very generic solution - having the position of integer in an array changed it will fail, as well as having the `arr2` changed will make this solution invalid :) P.S. I know you know

Comment: @AndreyDeineko I am not sure I follow. I believe those are dumped elements with ids in `arr1` and ids themselves in `arr2`. It will also fail on non-unique multiple values in `arr2` etc, but for the stated question this solution is robust enough.

Comment: Whatever those are, the question/request is `I want to extract entire array if it contains elements of arr2`, which your solution does not satisfy given the input data slightly changed. Even though with the provided examplary input it does solve it. `arr1 = [[1, "text1"], [2, 'text'], [5, "text5"], [6, "text6"], [7, "text7"]]`, which with your solution will result in `[]`, while it should result in `[[2, "text"], [6, "text6"]]`